# In a long and running Jupyter notebook, how to quickly locate the cell that is currently evaluating?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In a long, meaning it has many input cells such that the entire notebook spans across several screens, and currently running Jupyter notebook, how to quickly locate the cell that is currently evaluating?

Comment: how about ctrl-f [*] enter ?

Comment: This is a great question! I wish I knew.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546075/9201239