# How can I jump to the cell currently being run in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

After I select `run all`, `run all above`, or `run all below` in a Jupyter notebook, how can I jump to the cell currently being run?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for this idea, Aaron. But it works only once on a full run, so it needs to be improved to be more useful.

I have expanded it into a shortcut that can be used many times during the execution of the notebook.

add this to `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`:

```js
// Go to Running cell shortcut
Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('Alt-I', {
    help : 'Go to Running cell',
    help_index : 'zz',
    handler : function (event) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Find running cell and click the first one
            if ($('.running').length > 0) {
                //alert("found running cell");
                $('.running')[0].scrollIntoView();
            }}, 250);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now you can press `Alt-I` any time to have the notebook refocus the view on to the running cell.

Next it'd be nice to write an extension/shortcut that keeps the current running cell's view in focus during all of execution.

Comment: Will this work to find the last ran cell? If not how to adjust it to do so?

Comment: I asked that the jupyter team [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4323) - got no answer.

Answer (score 4):

Although not particularly elegant, when I need custom functionality like this I make use of jupyter's [custom.js](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.html).

The following snippet binds to the buttons' click events and selects the currently executing cell. You can place it in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`

```
$('#run_all_cells, #run_all_cells_above, #run_all_cells_below').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Find running cell and click the first one
        if ($('.running').length > 0) {
            $('.running')[0].click();
        }
    }, 250);
});
```